# TCL: Avoid timeout/unresponsive wish window during a long recursive calculation

Tags: recursion, timeout, tcl

I have written a script which will call a proc recursively until a solution is achieved. The problem is my wish window is getting unresponsive meanwhile. It is not printing the puts statement I have added for logging. I understand the script is busy in the calculation but why the puts are not getting printed to stdout?

How to keep the script/wish window alive during such long recursive procedure call.Here is the complete script.

```
namespace eval chainReactionGlobal {
    #variable state  [list 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    variable pos     [list 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
    variable posMax  [list 1 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 1]
    variable burstPos [list {1 3} {0 2 4} {1 5} {0 4 6} {1 3 5 7} {2 4 8} {3 7} {4 6 8} {5 7}]
    variable players [list A B C]
    variable boxLen   3
    variable boxWidth 3
}

proc ShowGraphicalState {state} {
    set length $chainReactionGlobal::boxLen
    set width $chainReactionGlobal::boxWidth
    puts "\n"
    puts "--------------------"
    puts -nonewline "\| [lindex $state 0][string repeat " " [expr 4-[string length [lindex $state 0]]]]\|"
    puts -nonewline "\| [lindex $state 1][string repeat " " [expr 4-[string length [lindex $state 1]]]]\|"
    puts -nonewline "\| [lindex $state 2][string repeat " " [expr 4-[string length [lindex $state 2]]]]\|"
    puts "\n--------------------"
    puts -nonewline "\| [lindex $state 3][string repeat " " [expr 4-[string length [lindex $state 3]]]]\|"
    puts -nonewline "\| [lindex $state 4][string repeat " " [expr 4-[string length [lindex $state 4]]]]\|"
    puts -nonewline "\| [lindex $state 5][string repeat " " [expr 4-[string length [lindex $state 5]]]]\|"
    puts "\n--------------------"
    puts -nonewline "\| [lindex $state 6][string repeat " " [expr 4-[string length [lindex $state 6]]]]\|"
    puts -nonewline "\| [lindex $state 7][string repeat " " [expr 4-[string length [lindex $state 7]]]]\|"
    puts -nonewline "\| [lindex $state 8][string repeat " " [expr 4-[string length [lindex $state 8]]]]\|"
    puts "\n--------------------"
}

proc GetNextPlayer {currentPlayer} {
    set currIdx [lsearch $chainReactionGlobal::players $currentPlayer]
    if {[expr $currIdx+1]<[llength $chainReactionGlobal::players ]} {
        return [lindex $chainReactionGlobal::players [expr $currIdx+1]]
    } else {
        return  [lindex $chainReactionGlobal::players 0]
    }    
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This function will take input of a stable state and current player, will
# return list of possible unstable state the current player can make.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
proc GetPossibleStateMatrix {stableState currentPlayer} {
    array set stateList {}

    foreach position $chainReactionGlobal::pos {

        set localState $stableState
        set currentPosValue [lindex $localState $position]  
        if {$currentPosValue=="0"} {
            lset localState $position [string repeat $currentPlayer 1]
        set stateList($position) $localState
        } elseif {[regexp -all $currentPlayer $currentPosValue]>0} {
            lset localState $position $currentPosValue$currentPlayer
            set stateList($position) $localState
        }


    }

    return [array get stateList]
}



proc GetStabilizedState {unstableState impactPosList} {
    set isStable 0
    set affectedPosList {}
    while {!$isStable} {
        foreach position $impactPosList {
            set posValue [lindex $unstableState $position]
            if { $posValue=="0"} {
                    set posLength 0
            } else {
                set posLength [string length $posValue]
            }
            set posMaxLength [lindex $chainReactionGlobal::posMax $position]

            if {($posLength>$posMaxLength)} {
                if {[expr $posLength-$posMaxLength-1] > 0} {
                    lset unstableState $position [string repeat [string range $posValue 0 0] [expr [expr $posLength-$posMaxLength]-1]]
                } else {
                    lset unstableState $position "0"
                }

                foreach affectedPos [lindex $chainReactionGlobal::burstPos $position] {
                    set affectedPosValue [lindex $unstableState $affectedPos]
                    if { $affectedPosValue =="0"} {
                        set affectedPosValueLength 0
                    } else {
                        set affectedPosValueLength [string length $affectedPosValue]
                    }
                    set affectedPosMaxLength [lindex $chainReactionGlobal::posMax $affectedPos]

                    if {[expr $affectedPosValueLength+1]>$affectedPosMaxLength } {
                        if {[lsearch $affectedPosList $affectedPos ] ==-1} {
                            lappend affectedPosList $affectedPos 
                        }
                    }
                    lset unstableState $affectedPos [string repeat [string range $posValue 0 0] [expr 1+$affectedPosValueLength]]      
                }
            }
        }

        set isStable 1
        foreach position $chainReactionGlobal::pos {
            set posValue [lindex $unstableState $position]
        if { $posValue=="0"} {
                set posLength 0
        } else {
            set posLength [string length $posValue]
        }
        set posMaxLength [lindex $chainReactionGlobal::posMax $position]
            if {($posLength>$posMaxLength) && ($posValue!="0")} {
                set isStable 0
            }
        }

        if {$isStable==1} { 
            return $unstableState
        }
        set impactPosList $affectedPosList
    }

}


proc IsImmediateWin {state currentPlayer} {
    foreach elem $state {
        if {$elem==0} {
            continue
        } elseif {[regexp $currentPlayer $elem]} {
            continue
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    return 1
}

    proc GetWinRatio {state myPlayer currentPlayer {test 0}} {

        puts "test $test state $state  myPlayer  $myPlayer currentPlayer $currentPlayer"

        set loss 0
        set win 0
        set possibleStateList [GetPossibleStateMatrix $state $currentPlayer]
        array set possibleStateArr $possibleStateList
        # puts possibleStateList$possibleStateList
        foreach possiblePos [lsort [array names possibleStateArr]] {
            set possibleState $possibleStateArr($possiblePos)
            puts "possibleState ----> $possibleState                          possiblePos  $possiblePos"
            set stableState [GetStabilizedState $possibleState $possiblePos]
            puts "stableState ----> $stableState"


            if {[IsImmediateWin $stableState $currentPlayer]} {
                if {$currentPlayer==$myPlayer } {
                    incr win
                } else {
                    incr loss
                }
            } else {
            puts "not immediate win"

                 set result [GetWinRatio $stableState $myPlayer [GetNextPlayer $currentPlayer] [expr $test+1] ]
                # set result "0:0"
                set winRes [lindex [split $result ":"] 0]
                set lossRes [lindex [split $result ":"] 1]

                incr win $winRes
                incr loss $lossRes
            }
            # puts "state [ShowGraphicalState $stableState]   wins:$win loss:$loss"

        }
        return ${win}:${loss}
    }
    puts "[GetWinRatio [list A CC A A B B A B C] A A]"
```

Comment: Which platform are you running this on?

Comment: I ran the script in Wish86.exe running on windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Wish, that is why you need a `Tk` command `update` or `update idletasks`. You don't need this command when you are using tclsh in console.

I can't test your code because of function `GetPossibleStateMatrix` is absent.
So, i've tested code like this:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 10000} {incr i} {puts $i}
```

Yes, there is no output until the end of execution. So, i've added `update` command:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 10000} {incr i} {puts $i; update}
```

And now I can see the output in the process of execution.

Try to add `update` command after your first `puts`:

```
proc GetWinRatio {state myPlayer currentPlayer {test 0}} {

    puts "test $test state $state  myPlayer  $myPlayer currentPlayer $currentPlayer"
    update
    . . .
```

Comment: @Codename_DJ I've added the `update` command after each `puts` and run you code. It was quickly showed:
test 3 state A CC 0 AA CCC C A CC C  myPlayer  A currentPlayer A
possibleState ----> AA CC 0 AA CCC C A CC C                          possiblePos
  0


and after that stoped responding. Looks like problem in `GetStabilizedState` function.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong place all this time :). Thanks for the hint about update.

Comment: I’m sorry for my poorly written comments and numerous errors. I can’t edit them.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Tk console is actually running in a separate interpreter context in the main thread. It has its own Tk window hierarchy, but shares a primary event loop with your Tcl code. Unfortunately, this means that if you make your Tcl code running in the main interpreter very busy (e.g., by doing a lot of processing), it ceases to process display updates in the console. The text is there in the window model, but the actual code to process that as real display updates is in a callback that is scheduled in an idle event.

The fix is to put either `update` or `update idletasks` inside your main processing loop somewhere. The latter is sufficient to process display updates from the `puts` calls, but the former allows you to also interact with the window (e.g., scroll it). The down side is that you could process other events in your main window too, and you either need to be careful as a user or update your GUI so as to lock people out while the long processing is going on. There's lots of different ways of doing that, but if it is just for your own use, the “just be careful” approach works fine.